# Quotient of polynomial ring is product of fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Please just give me some hints on how to attack this problem. Suppose that $F$ is a field, $I \subseteq F[X]$ is a nonzero ideal and $F[X]/I$ has no nilpotent elements other than 0. Show that $F[X]/I$ is a product of fields. Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 4):

You have that $I=(f)$ for some polynomimal $f$. Factor $f$ into irreducibles. If the factorization of $f$ isn't squarefree, demonstrate the existence of a nonzero nilpotent element.

If it is squarefree, apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem to $\prod_{p|f} R/(p)$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Doh, yes! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case if and only if $\sqrt I=I$. An ideal $I$ in $F[X]$ is radical if and only if its generator is a square-free polynomial...